# Configuring jboss to send mails from microsoft exchange server using java mail api

Tags: java, email, jboss

We have a requirement to send mails from microsoft exchange server using java mail api and JBoss AS 7.1.2.FINAL.

I am able send mails using gmail smtp server from jboss. Configuration is given below.

```
<profile>  
     <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:1.0">
        <mail-session jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
            <smtp-server ssl="true" outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp">
                <login name="emailid@gmail.com" password="password"/>
            </smtp-server>
        </mail-session>
     </subsystem>
  </profile>
  <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
     <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="smtp.gmail.com" port="465"/>
     </outbound-socket-binding>
  </socket-binding-group>
```

I am able to send mails from microsfot exchange server using EWS java api(from normal java class and not from jboss).

But, I am unable to find solution for sending mails from microsoft exchange server using java mail api and jboss.

If anyone knows how to configure, please let me know. Also let me know even if we can configure in any other versions of jboss.